# SQL query in Databricks to return the value of subtraction of time?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

[image: The example table]

From the following table, my goal is to fill in the value in the column "clmnTimeDiff". Suppose that I have clmnTime1 and clmnTime2, which store the value of "TIME" in string, I want to let the field clmnTimeDiff store the difference between clmnTime2 and clmnTime1. From this table, in the record ID = 1, the result in clmnTimeDiff should be 23:14:31 - 12:15:47 = hh:mm:ss.
Actually, the full table contains clmnDate1 and clmnDate2 as well. Previously, I thought that I can follow this query:

```
SELECT 
      ID
     ,clmnTime1
     ,clmnTime2
     ,CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CAST(CONCAT(clmnDate2, ' ', clmnTime2) AS TIMESTAMP), 
      CAST(CONCAT(clmnDate1, ' ', clmnTime1) AS TIMESTAMP)),
      ':'
     ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(CONCAT(clmnDate2, ' ', clmnTime2) AS TIMESTAMP), 
      CAST(CONCAT(clmnDate1, ' ', clmnTime1) AS TIMESTAMP)),
      ':'
     ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, CAST(CONCAT(clmnDate2, ' ', clmnTime2) AS TIMESTAMP), 
      CAST(CONCAT(clmnDate1, ' ', clmnTime1) AS TIMESTAMP))) AS clmnTimeDiff
FROM example_table
```

The problem is that my Databricks does not support TIMESTAMPDIFF(), so I'm running out of idea to solve this problem. How can I get the value in clmnTimeDiff?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on what you are going for, but here is a guess

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([clmnTime1] varchar(50),[clmnTime2] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('12:15:47','23:14:31')
 
Select *
      ,NewVal = convert(time,dateadd(second,datediff(second,try_convert(time,clmnTime1),try_convert(time,clmnTime2) ),0))
 from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
clmnTime1   clmnTime2   NewVal
12:15:47    23:14:31    10:58:44
```